# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: java, oracle, jwt

I am trying to insert JWT token in database for particular user_id(column) before sending it out to the client.

```
public void saveTokenToDB(String email, String token) {
        try {
            String query = "Update TBL_USER set USR_TOKEN ="+token+" where email="+email+" ";
            Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            int result = statement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("result is: " + result);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in TokenSaverDAO class");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I get an error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

I tried using CLOB as column type but still get the same error.

This is my token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvcnRoLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IlJUSCIsImV4cCI6MTQ1MzE1NDI2MywiZW1haWwiOiJraXJpdGkuazk5OUBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ
.X13gGlAIbS3bh-2eX-SdZjglA-QSMW5Gz_IokRdGWXqmmdQDYHNgbKpuqhtf7EqSLN_I8Qx80FMKzVXn9G4O1-bhXCDkWWHkPaC
WN16RJazyJdWqzHHTVHD2AN-mF6eG7KFto5HlvFfIdvgQZszAzqS_cVGQHM1hIn-r5sCrkI4
```

Is there any other way to save the token in DB or may be saving it in map for each user who's logged in. If I use map then how do I do the authentication each time user request for a resource.

Right now I am doing this:

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // Get the HTTP Authorization header from the request
        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // Check if the HTTP Authorization header is present and formatted correctly 
        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
        }

        // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
        String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();
        System.out.println("request token is: " + token);

        try {

            // Validate the token
            validateToken(token);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(
                    Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }
    }

    private void validateToken(String token) throws Exception {
        // Check if the token was issued by the server that is saved in Database and if it's not expired
        // Throw an Exception if the token is invalid
    }
}
```

Two questions here:

1. How to fix java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
2. Saving token in map or cache and performing the JWT authentication on
   each resource request

Comment: Learn about prepared statements. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Strings must be inside quotes, and special characters need to be escaped. A prepared statement will care of all this for you.

Comment: String values need to be quoted, a PreparedStatement would do that automatically for you.

Comment: @JBNizet What is wrong in my query? I have updated the question. Please check. The parameters "email" and "token" are coming from method call.

Comment: @Henry please check my updated question. Thank you

Comment: Again, you do not quote the token value in the SQL statement.

Comment: @Henry If I use it like this: `String query = "Update TBL_USER set USR_TOKEN = +token+ where email=+email+";` I get an error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression`

Comment: Only one question per question please. 2) should be a new question

Comment: I told you what is wrong. To update the string column foo with the value "abc" in a column, the syntax is `update table bar set foo = 'abc'`. Not `update table bar set foo = abc`. Use a prepared statement, that will do that for you, prevent SQL injection attacks, and quote special characters in parameters.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. I understood where I went wrong. Yeah I guess I should change it to preparedStatement. tx again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
String query = "Update TBL_USER set USR_TOKEN ="+token+" where email="+email+" ";
```

Assuming `token` contains the String `"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9"` you wind up with this statement

```
Update TBL_USER set USR_TOKEN = eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9
```

which references a column named `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9`. If your token was shorter you'd get an "invalid identifier" error. But the extremely long value for the token breaks the SQL parser in an earlier state because identifiers are limited to 30 characters (so the most basic syntax check fails and Oracle doesn't even start checking if there is a column with that name).

---

String constants need to be enclosed in singlequotes, e.g. `'foobar'`, so your Java code needs to be:

```
String query = "Update TBL_USER set USR_TOKEN = '" + token + "' where email = '"+email+"' ";
```

But this will break if the variables `email` or `token` contain single quotes. To fix *that* problem it is much better to use a PreparedStatement correctly:

```
String query = "Update TBL_USER set USR_TOKEN = ? where email = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(1, token);
statement.setString(2, email);
int result = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: In your answer you're saying the identifiers are limited to 30 characters which is why the basic syntax check fails. But the identifier 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9' isn't even 30 characters long. Why does I get the exception then?

Comment: @watchme: did you see the real token in the question?

Comment: oh sorry :D Because in my program the same exception is thrown, but no column identifier seems to be "too long"...

Comment: @watchme: most probably the same reason. You are not (properly) using a `PreparedStatement` and on top of that you are (incorrectly) using double quotes for string constants

Comment: Where is it specified, that identifiers are limited to 30 characters?

Comment: @BdN3504: [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) - however this restriction has been lifted with Oracle 12.2 (which was not available in 2016 when I wrote this answer) and is now at 128 bytes

Comment: Thanks for the reference! For mysql the restrictions can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html

Comment: Well, obviously those restrictions are documented in the manual of each database. But I fail to see how the MySQL restriction is of any importance in a question regarding Oracle.